# Distinct Values in WPF Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, combobox, distinct

I would like to get distinct values in my databound combo box

as an example the values it has are: blue, blue, yellow, red, orange

I would like it to just display blue once.

My main thought was to get all combo box values into an array, set the array as distinct and then re-populate the combo box. Is there any other way?

If not how would I actually get all the values from the combo box?

Thanks

EDIT -- Class:

```
public class DistinctConverter : IValueConverter
{

}
```

EDIT -- Debug:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create an `IValueConverter` that converts your list into a distinct list:

```
public class DistinctConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var values = value as IEnumerable;
        if (values == null)
            return null;
        return values.Cast<object>().Distinct();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

add this to resources:

```xml
<local:DistinctConverter x:Key="distinctConverter" />
```

and use it like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Vals, Converter={StaticResource distinctConverter}}" />
```

Comment: How would you create a converter?

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm having trouble entering the <local:... I have set the namespace: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectName" but can't get <local:DistinctConverter to work. Stating the type DistinctConverter could not be found.

Comment: @Sandeep, as long as the converter is in the namespace you specified in the `xmlns:local` attribute and in the same assembly as the XAML class, that should work.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work :s xmlns:local is stated as my projects name, and have entered the Convert method into my MainPage.xaml.cs and entered the <local:DistinctConverter x:Key="distinctConverter" /> in the UserControl.Resources tag, yet it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Sandeep, oh, sorry, I was unclear. You have to create a class called `DistinctConverter` that implements the `IValueConverter` interface.

Comment: I've changed my question with code, do I just implement the interface how I did there, or do I do it another way?

Comment: +1 Its a good answer, it would clearly be improved if you add the small amount of code to turn the `Convert` method into a complete class.  That would really help.

Comment: @Anthony, I didn't add the complete before, because I thought it was clear and trivial.

Comment: @svick I managed to get it all to compile and run but the combo box returns nothing :s. I'm using something like this: ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=showDomainDataSource, Path=Data, Converter={StaticResource distinctConverter}}"

Comment: @Sandeep, that should work. Does it work without the converter?

Comment: The values are in the combo box without the Converter, but when I use the converter resource it just shows a blank

Comment: @Sandeep, then try debugging the converter split the line with `return`, so that it first places the results to a variable and then returns that. Then place a breakpoint to the `Convert()` method and watch what it does and what it ultimately returns.

Comment: I hit a breakpoint at the return values.Cast<object.... and the results came out as Enumeration yielded no results

Comment: @Sandeep, and `value` does contain elements and it's of type that implements `IEnumerable`? That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Yes that's right, I have edited my question with a screenshot of the debug.

Comment: @Sandeep, from that it seems your value is empty, so it shouldn't display anything, with or without converter.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your you have a `List<String> values =  blue, blue, yellow, red, orange`

you can do

```
ComboBox.ItemsSource = values.Distinct();
```

or if you are going for MVVM approach you can create a property and bind combo box itemssource with a property like

```
public List<string> values
{
    get
    {
    return value.Distinct();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if you are using WPF c# 4.0

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
        foreach (object o in myComboBox.Items)
            {
            if (!list.Contains(o))
                {
                list.Add(o);
                }
            }
        myComboBox.Items.Clear();
        myComboBox.ItemsSource=list.ToArray();
```