# WPF hide duplicates with CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one `ObservableCollection<M> fooBar {get;set;}`. The class `M.cs` looks like this:

```
public class M{
    private int _ID;
    public int ID {
        get {return this._ID;}
        set {this._ID = value;}
    }

    private string _number;
    public int Number {
        get {return this._number;}
        set {this._number = value;}
    }

    private string _power;
    public int Power {
        get {return this._power;}
        set {this._power = value;}
    }

    /*
       ...
    */
}
```

Now I want to hide only the duplicates of the propery `Power`. Inside my `.xaml` code I wrote this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myCollection" Source="{Binding Path=fooBar}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Power"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I bind this collection to my `ComboBox`.

```
<ComboBox Name="cbValues" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCollection}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Power}" 
    SelectedValuePath="{Binding Power}"
    />
```

The `ComboBox` is filled with the correct values, but there a still duplicates. How can I hide them?

Comment: Avoid duplicates when filling the data to the collection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distinct Values in WPF Combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995989/distinct-values-in-wpf-combobox)

Comment: @Eldho different machine`s can have the same power source.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a [`CollectionViewSource.Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
myCollection.Filter+= new FilterEventHandler(ShowOnlyDistinctFilter);
```

This event handler uses to filter and show the data that are relevant to your data source

```
private void ShowOnlyDistinctFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var item= e.Item as M;
    if (item != null)
    {
       //Your distinct logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: THanks for the answer! I have still one problem. The displayed property is based on another `ComboBox`. So the property can be `Power`, `ID` or `Number`. Can you explain your code a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

I too have this issue, and couldn't find a good answer, so here's the Generic solution I came up with.

Works well with multiple CollectionViewSources where, at least in my case, each CollectionViewSource needed to be distinct on a different object.

Here's the Generic Method:

You only need to insure that T is the same type as the CollectionViewSource.Source.

```
    private void cvs_filter_distinct<T>(CollectionViewSource sender, FilterEventArgs e, Func<T, T, bool> arg)
    {

        if (e.Item != null)
        {
            switch (sender.View.IsEmpty)
            {
                case true:

                    e.Accepted = true;

                    break;
                default:       

                    switch ((sender.View.Cast<T>()).All(x => arg(x, (T)e.Item)))
                    {
                        case true:

                            e.Accepted = true;
                            break;
                        default:

                            e.Accepted = false;
                            break;
                    }  
                    break;
            }     
        }
    }
```

**Sample:**

Given a object like:

```
    public class My_Class
    {
        public string String_A { get; set; }
        public string String_B { get; set; }
    }
```

With a data collection and a CollectionViewSource like:

```
    public ObservableCollection<My_Class> My_Data_Collection = new ObservableCollection<My_Class>();
    public CollectionViewSource My_CollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
```

We add the generic filter, and "curry" the argument Function via lambda:

```
public void Some_Methood()
    {
        My_CollectionViewSource.Source = My_Data_Collection;



        My_CollectionViewSource.Filter += 
            new FilterEventHandler(
                (sender, e) => cvs_filter_distinct<My_Class>(
                    sender:(CollectionViewSource)sender, 
                    e: e, 
                    arg: (a, b) => a.String_A != b.String_A));


    }
```

For me this is nice, as I can specify what object's to compare and how to compare them.  Additionally I dont have to write a separate filter method for each CollectionViewSource.

And if you want to get fancy, you can expand it to filter based on items in another collection, like so:

```
    private void cvs_filter_distinct<T, O>(CollectionViewSource sender, FilterEventArgs e, Func<T, O, bool> arg, O[] otherCollection)
    {
        T[] _view_values;

        if (e.Item != null)
        {
            switch (sender.View.IsEmpty)
            {
                case true:

                    e.Accepted = true;

                    break;
                default:

                    _view_values =
                        sender
                        .View
                        .Cast<T>()
                        .ToArray();

                    e.Accepted =
                        otherCollection
                        .All(a => _view_values
                            .All(a2 => arg(a2, a)));

                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private class My_Other_Class
    {
        public string Another_String { get; set; }
    }


    public void Some_Other_Methood()
    {
        My_Other_Class[] my_other_data_collection = new My_Other_Class[] {
            new My_Other_Class() {
                Another_String = "some other text" } };

        
        My_CollectionViewSource.Source = My_Data_Collection;
        

        My_CollectionViewSource.Filter +=
            new FilterEventHandler(
                (sender, e) => cvs_filter_distinct<My_Class,My_Other_Class>(
                    sender: (CollectionViewSource)sender,
                    e: e,
                    arg: (a, b) => a.String_A != b.Another_String,
                    otherCollection: my_other_data_collection));


    }
```