# ComboBox to show only unique values of a field in an ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with its ItemSource bound to an `ICollectionView` (for filtering). I'm trying to have a ComboBox which will filter the **EffectiveDate** column in the DataGid, its ItemsSource (dropdown values) should be the **EffectiveDate** of all currently available rows (there are other filters too) in the DataGrid.

Here's the code:

In the **MainWindow:**

```
<DataGrid Name="ProductsList"
          ItemsSource="{Binding PricesView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Sku}" Header="Sku"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Upc}" Header="UPC"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cost}" Header="Cost"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Map}" Header="MAP"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding List.EffectiveDate, StringFormat=d}" Header="List Effective Date"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding List.Vendor.Name}" Header="Vendor"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PricesView}" DisplayMemberPath="List.EffectiveDate"/>
```

In the **MainWIndowViewModel:**

```
public ICollectionView PricesView { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<Price> Prices { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Price>(DataAccess.GetVendorPricing());

public MainWIndowViewModel()
{
    PricesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Prices);
}
```

**Price Class:**

```
public class Price
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public PriceList List { get; set; }
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Upc { get; set; }
        public double Cost { get; set; }
        public double Map { get; set; }
    }
```

**`List` above is of type `PriceList`:** (Here's where you find the `EffectiveDate` property)

```
  public class PriceList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    }
```

The issue is that the ComboBox brings up the **EffecitveDate** for each row (thousands of them!), what I need is just the unique values.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995989/distinct-values-in-wpf-combobox) method, using an `IValueConverter`, the problem is that converter takes in the entire `ICollectionView` without the  `DisplayMemberPath` and returns distinct values of the entire collection (which is basically everything), what I'm after is distinct values of only this specific field.

How can I have the ComboBox only show unique values of **EffectiveDate**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your records immutable?
If so, you could publish a property on the ViewModel to obtain the distinct grouped values using Linq:

```
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> DistinctDates
    {
        get
        {
            return from item in this.PricesView.Cast<Price>()
                   group item by item.List.EffectiveDate into g
                   select g.Key;
        }
    }
```

`<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DistinctDates}" />`

If the data can be edited it is more difficult and you should notify the "DistinctDate" property change or search for another method...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

use distinc in sql when you load the data from reader

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your Connectionstring"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Your select Query", conn);

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                IList<string> listName = new List<string>();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    listName.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
                listName = listName.Distinct().ToList();
                ComboBox1.DataSource = listName;
            }</string></string>
```