# Distinct value display on WPF ComboBox Programmatically (ItemsSource DataTable AsDataView)

Tags: wpf

I have a DataTable, and a ComboBox gets items from this table as:

```
SQLiteDataAdapter sQLiteDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(_command);
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Alarm");
sQLiteDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

cboxAlarmFilterSeverity.DisplayMemberPath = "severity";
cboxAlarmFilterSeverity.SelectedValuePath = "severity";
cboxAlarmFilterSeverity.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
```

I want to get only **distinct values** to ComboBox. I know, I could use this query, but I do not want to use:

```
_command.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT severity FROM [Alarm]";
```

And I could use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5996116/7652968), but it should not interact with XAML, it should be programmatically.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataView` has a `ToTable` method that creates a new `DataTable` that contains rows that have distinct values:

```
cboxAlarmFilterSeverity.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView()
    .ToTable(true, "severity")
    .DefaultView;
```